# Configuring XRDP for archlinux

Tags: xrdp

After installing `xrdp` on Arch Linux, I can connect to the desktop remotely, but after entering the password of the newly created user, I have a blank screen.

How much did I understand I need to specify the desktop in the XRDP configuration file?

Comment: Maybe [Arch  Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xrdp) would be helpful.